# How to groupByKey and count occurances of values coressponsing to the keys in spark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

```
t: Array[(Int, String)] = Array((24210720,s503), (24210742,s500), (24210742,s500), (24210748,s503))
```

I have an array of of key values pairs. I would like to reduce/groupby (I am not sure which one to use) by key and would like to have coreesponding value as a map of value count. Should look something like

24210720 => {s503=>1} , 24210742 => {s500=>2}, 24210748 => {s503=>1}

So finally i  would like to print
24210720:s503:1
24210742:s500:2
24210748:s503:1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is just to print the count for each couple of values,than you can simply do:

```
rdd=sc.parallelize(t);
rdd.map(x=>( x, 1) ).reduceByKey(_+_).map(x => x._1._1+":"+x._1._2+":"+x._2 )
```

Comment: This is precisely what I needed. You made my day. Thanks for such a simple and elegant solution.